# oo7-parity How to deploy a contract with initialization code

Tags: parity, oo7js

Following the tutorial here, I know how to use oo7-parity to deploy a new contract. https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Tutorial-Part-9

```
deploy () {
    let tx = bonds.deployContract(CounterCode, CounterABI);
```

The example contract `Counter` has no contract constructor, so it can be deployed with only contract byte code and ABI.

However, suppose a contract has a constructor function and initialization variables like the following one, how should I put the variable (`_greeting`) in the `bonds.deployContract` function?

```
contract greeter{
    string greeting;
    function greeter(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here's how I do it. You'll need web3js 0.20.0, use it's `getData` function to generate the new byte code which contains encoded initialization variables.

```
const web3 = new Web3()
let MyContract = web3.eth.contract(MyABI)
let _greeting = "my init variable"
let newByteCode = MyContract.new.getData(_greeting, {data: oldByteCode})
let tx = bonds.deployContract(newByteCode, MyABI)
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs state:

> You'll need to either get your own byte code from the compiler

So you can either user [browser solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity) or the [javascript compiler](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js).

Comment: Indeed, the byte code can be generated through the compiler. But the initialization variables still needs to be specified after that, even on  browser solidity. [photo](https://imgur.com/a/V2Q5D)